# Web Scraping from a dynamic graph using Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, urlfetch

I'm trying to grab data from one of my third-party software.
I need to login first, then I get to see a graph that gives me the number of sales on a daily basis. Note that I'm using this script ID (Google Apps Script Library) for `Parser`: 1Mc8BthYthXx6CoIz90-JiSzSafVnT6U3t0z_W3hLTAX5ek4w0G_EIrNw

My script should:

- Login to the website
- Grab the data from yesterday
- Put this in a Google sheet

In this example (see image below), I'm interested to grab the number "13"

[image]

based on this [explanation](https://www.kutil.org/2016/01/easy-data-scrapping-with-google-apps.html), I created this script.

```
function callHubspotsApi() {

  const payload =
    {
     "username" : "myemail",
     "password" : "mypassword",
       };

  const options =
  {
     "method" : "post",
     "payload" : payload,
     "followRedirects" : false,
  };

  const login = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://app.hubspot.com/login" , options);
  const sessionDetails = login.getAllHeaders();
  // console.log(sessionDetails); //for debugging the login information
}

  const timezone = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  const today = new Date();
  const yesterdayAsaString = new Date(new Date().setDate(today.getDate() - 1));
  const yesterday = Utilities.formatDate(yesterdayAsaString, timezone, "MM/dd/yyyy");
  // console.log(yesterday); //for debugging the date
  
  const url = "https://app.hubspot.com/reports-dashboard/6281552/view/3786627?rangeType=THIS_MONTH&frequency=DAY"; 
  const content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  //const fromText = '<span class="selected">';
  const fromText = '<div class="tooltip-header">8/10/2022</div>';
  const toText = '<div id="highcharts-screen-reader-region-after-0" aria-label="" aria-hidden="false" style="position: relative;"><div aria-hidden="false" style="position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); margin-top: -3px; opacity: 0.01;"><div id="highcharts-end-of-chart-marker-0">End of interactive chart.</div></div></div>';

  var scraped = Parser.data(content).from(fromText).to(toText).build();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(Sheet1);
 sheet.appendRow([ new Date(), getData() ]);

}
```

My problems:

- Script displayed an error message
- When I run `console.log(scraped);` it doesn't give me the '13' value I want
- Maybe it's related to the fact I did not include any login details?

I would appreciate any kind of help. Thank you !

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `Script displayed an error message`? And, in your situation, you have already succeeded `Login to the website`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Tanaike, I did not succeed to login yet. I think this is the reason why my script displayed an error. This is the message displayed in the console: `"An unknown error has occurred, please try again later."`

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I did not succeed to login yet.`, when you try to log in using your showing script, `Script displayed an error message` occurs. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike I've edited the script to add the login part. But I still get the same error message. It would be great if you could you have a look at this page:  https://app.hubspot.com/login I would like to know first if my script can successfully login to the website. Then I can work on the part about web scraping. Thank you so much

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I would like to know first if my script can successfully login to the website.`, in this case, I cannot test the script for logging in. So, unfortunately, I cannot propose an answer. This is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I understand. If you know the URL: https://app.hubspot.com/login and `inspect` the elements in the web browsers, do you think you could see what is wrong with my script? If not it's ok

Comment: Thank you for replying. If your script for logging in to your site is required to be modified, I think that it is required to test the script. Because I have no information for logging in to your site. In your showing script, it seems that the script after the log-in is included. For example, if your script for logging in works, if you provide the data of `content` and your expected values, I think that I can think of the modification points.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I could create a dummy account with the following login details: username: fereqaxe@forexnews.bg / password: Tanaike404. As per my first request, I just want to get the </span> number. Do you think it would be doable?

Comment: I'm guessing my script is almost ready for the login part. Maybe just few lines of codes are missing but I donno how to fix it :(

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested the login using your sample account, it seems that 2FA is required to be used. By this, I cannot test for logging in. I apologize for this.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I understand thank you for trying this out. Do you have any solution other than web scraping or API that could allow me to get the data by any chance?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Do you have any solution other than web scraping or API that could allow me to get the data by any chance?`, I would like to support you. But, in this case, I cannot log in to your site, and also I have no information about your site. So, in the current stage, I cannot propose another direction or a workaround. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again.